Getting a Failed to resolve import error even though I am mentioning the correct file path and have exported the variables
I am trying to make a chatting application using React with Vite and Firebase using Google authentication.
I created a firebase.js file to contain the firebase SDK and credentials, when I am importing the auth variable to my App.jsx and NavBar.jsx components it throws an error saying
[vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to resolve import "./firebase.js" from "src/components/NavBar.jsx". Does the file exist?
11:06:45 am [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "./firebase.js" from "src/components/NavBar.jsx". Does the file exist?  
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: C:/Users/kevin/react-chat-app/src/components/NavBar.jsx:2:21
  17 |  var _s = $RefreshSig$();
  18 |  import React, { useState } from "react";
  19 |  import { auth } from "./firebase.js";
     |                        ^
  20 |  import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
  21 |  import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { auth } from './firebase.js'; // Make sure this import is correct
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import ChatBox from './components/ChatBox';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome';

const App = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      {user ? <ChatBox /> : <Welcome />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


NavBar.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebase.js";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

const NavBar = () => {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const googleSignIn = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  };
  const googleSignOut = () => {
    auth.signOut();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <h1>Chat App</h1>
        {user ? (
          <button onClick={googleSignOut}>Sign Out</button>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={googleSignIn}>Sign In</button>
        )}
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;


firebase.js, it is correctly placed in the src folder of the vite app
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);

I tried changing the path to "../firebase.js" and "./src/firebase.js" even tried to move it to the components foler "./components/firebase.js" but nothing works
